# How can i start my webapp after running in tomcat via maven

Tags: java, maven, tomcat

I have an web app that i want to launch via maven using tomcat7.

in my pom.xml file i have this tomcat plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <path>/</path>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

when i run :

```
 mvn tomcat:run-war
```

my war is deployed in tomcat, but i also want launch the browser in de path

```
http://localhost:8080/
```

i found out that jetty plugin can do this, but i want to do it in tomcat plugin.

what i need to do to achive this ?

Comment: can you try with `cargo-maven2-plugin`. [Maven Reference Guide](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+Plugin+Reference+Guide.html) with [Maven Plugin document](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+plugin.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use mvn tomcat7:deploy instead